# PHP - remove key from joined arrays

Tags: php, arrays, join, key

I have 2 arrays.

```
$sv_json_en

$param
```

I pushed `$sv_json_en` inside `$param['params']`.

```
array_push($param['params'], $sv_json_en);
```

The result is this:

```
[
    'email' => 'mycar@mycar.pt',
    'title' => 'Carro 2',
    'params' => [
        'price' => [
            (int) 0 => 'price',
        ],
        (int) 0 => [
            'destaque' => '0',
            'titulo' => 'Carro 2',
        ]
]
```

The problem is that `$sv_json_en` is inserted has another key (int) 0 => [] from $params.

I need to remove key (int) 0 => [] and put it's keys => values in the same level as price (not inside price) which is the root level of 'params' => [].

I try with aritmetic join `$array1 + $array2`.
I also try with `array_merge`.

But maybe i need a loop like foreach loop with nested levels of iteration?

Any suggestions on how it is made?

Comment: `$param['params'] = array_merge($param['params'], $sv_json_en);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your starting arrays are:

```
$sv_json_en = [
    'destaque' => '0',
    'titulo' => 'Carro 2'
];

$param = [
    'email' => 'mycar@mycar.pt',
    'title' => 'Carro 2',
    'params' => [
        'price' => [
            0 => 'price',
        ]
    ]
];
```

Then the following should yield the result you are looking for:

```
$param['params'] = array_merge($param['params'], $sv_json_en);
```

Where

```
print_r($param);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [email] => mycar@mycar.pt
    [title] => Carro 2
    [params] => Array
        (
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => price
                )

            [destaque] => 0
            [titulo] => Carro 2
        )

)
```